# How would call on the values of a dictionary if a user enters lines of inputs?

Tags: python

i am a first university student learning python programming. we were given exercises to do in our own to help with practice. in this exercise our task is to write an app that will recognised whether a word is ‘hello’ in one of 6 languages. here are some details on it:

**Input** The input contains around 1000 lines of inputs. Each line contains a string S. You can assume that all the letters of the string are uppercase letters in plain ASCII A-Z and the maximum length of the string is 14. Input is terminated by a line containing a single ‘#’ character (without the quote); this line should not be processed.

**Output** For each line of input (except the last one), produce one line of output. This line contains simply the language name. If the input string is ‘HELLO’ or ‘MOLO’ or ‘HALLO’ or ‘SAWUBONA’
or ‘BONJOUR’ or ‘MARHABA’, then you should report the language it belongs to. If the input string is something other than these 6 strings, then print the string ‘UNKNOWN’ (without the quotes) instead. All characters in the output strings are uppercase as well.

- I was thinking of using dictionaries and using a 'for' loop which reads each line of user inputs, matches the user input to the keys in the dictionary and then prints out the dictionary values. i would then use an 'else' function to identify 'unknown' greetings. however, this does not seem to work and the '#' does not break the code.
  I have copied my code down below:

```
X = {"HELLO":"ENGLISH", "HALLO":"AFRIKAANS", "BONJOUR":"FRENCH", "MOLO":"ISIXHOSA", "SAWUBONA":"ISIZULU", "MARHABA":"ARABIC"}

#for i in range(key, key+1):
key = input("")
for key in X.keys():
    print(X[key])
    if key == '#':
        break
else: 
    print('UNKNOWN')
```

this is an example of an ideal sample input and ouput:
input:

```
HELLO
HALLO
BONJOUR
MOLO
SAWUBONA
CHAO
#
```

output:

```
ENGLISH
AFRIKAANS
FRENCH
ISIXHOSA
ISIZULU
UNKNOWN
```

my code produces the correct output when I enter this input, however if I were to enter an input of:

```
MOLO
BONJOUR
CHAO
HELLO
#
```

instead of getting the sample output of:

```
ARABIC
FRENCH
UNKNOWN
ENGLISH
```

I get:

```
ENGLISH
AFRIKAANS
FRENCH
ISIXHOSA
ISIZULU
UNKNOWN
```

I feel as if this is because my code is not actually reading the user input and then printing the matching variable. i feel as if this has to do with my 'for' loop but all other ideas i try to code are full of errors

Comment: the first approach is fine in my opinion.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It's not entirely clear what you expect from us.  "Is a for loop correct" is either an opinion (i.e. off-topic) or moot: does the program do what you expect?
**Overall**, you seem to be looking for generic tutorial guidance; this is off-topic.  Focus on a specific question -- *then* you have a good Stack Overflow post.

Comment: You say that one program "does not seem to work"; this is not a problem specification.
Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.